# Trying to create docker image and getting following error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

There are two project in the same solution One is Api project and another one is .net core project and I am trying to ship both the to docker, I am doing this by `docker-compose up -d` and getting following error

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rImLA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Docker container can't form a secure SSL connection to install the Nuget packages because you haven't installed your CA certificate on the container.

You can create your own certificate using Docker's tutorial [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#create-the-client-certificates).

Installing this will then depend on the OS or your base image. You can find instructions for installing certificates on different Linux OS's [here](https://support.kerioconnect.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015200119-Adding-Trusted-Root-Certificates-to-the-Server). You'll just have to move the required commands into your Dockerfile before running the nuget restore.